# Div in bottom of parent with spacing?

Tags: css

So I'm gonna describe my problem with a little help from an image.

[image: Website]

Problem: At the above post you can see the "My signature" sticks to the bottom of the post but on the second post you can see it ends right as the content for the post end.

Because it is a forum the height of the content is not set, it will vary depending on how long post the author writes.

The Code:
What I have right now is the signature have the CSS

```
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
```

and the whole post containing the content and the signature have

```
  position: relative;
```

Any ideas of how I may stick the signature to the bottom no matter what height the content above the signature have?

Edit: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkCc5/1/

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: @j08691 I added JSFiddle now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it the same as you have just add `padding-bottom:40px;` to `.topicContent` which is the height of your `.signature`

http://jsfiddle.net/QkCc5/2/

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems to work for me: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nsrny/). Maybe there is some other problem in your code or maybe your browser is to old?

CSS:

```
.post {
    position: relative;
}
.signature {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Update:

Try adding an `padding-bottom: 40px;` CSS rule to your post content container (not the post container itself)

Comment: I put together a little JSFiddle to better show the problem http://jsfiddle.net/QkCc5/1/

Comment: @user3740791 The JSFiddle is working for me. What is the browser and version of the browser that you are using?